# JSplitPane resetting divider positions

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I've got two JSplitPanes like so

```
splitPaneRight = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, console, tabPager);
splitPaneLeft = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, infoPanel, splitPaneRight);

splitPaneRight.setResizeWeight(1);
```

and a method that goes as following and is normally called by a click on a JMenuItem somewhere else:

```
public void resetLayout()
{
    setSize(1280, 720);
    splitPaneLeft.setDividerLocation(165);
    splitPaneRight.setDividerLocation(830);
}
```

The interface looks like this (clickable thumbnail):

[Main user interface http://bit-stab.com/pictures/dump/MinecraftRemoteAdmin_thumb.jpg](http://bit-stab.com/pictures/dump/MinecraftRemoteAdmin.jpg)

my problem is, whenever I move the position of both divider I have to press that menu item twice before both dividers are back in place. The left one always goes on the first time, and the right on the second.

I have tried changing the order in which the dividers are set (right first, then left). I've tried invalidating, the splitpane of the changed divider, both splitpanes, and both splitpanes plus the UI (extends JFrame)

I've also tried running the method twice when the menu item is pressed. Or checking if getDividerLocation() returns the value that I've just set (which it does for some weird reason).

And last but not least, I've tried combinations of all of the above.

I'm running out of ideas, does there exist a working fix for this?

EDIT: I've created a runnable example (source: http://pastebin.com/VKtN6zJZ), [download.jar](http://bit-stab.com/pictures/dump/JSplitPane_Problem_Example.jar)

Comment: setDividerLocation is wrong sizing, setSize is wrong. setsize, then to setDividerLocations is wrong, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable just about JFrame with two (empty) JSplitPanes

Comment: @mKorbel example created

Comment: @StabbedBit, you were asked to post a SSCCE. A SSCCE is typically short enough so that the code can be posted in the forum. There is no need to create a runnable jar. We don't have time to unpack the jar to look at the source code. The easier it is for us to look at the code the more likely we will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setSize(1280, 720);
```

Never hardcode sizes like that. Not everybody will be using the same resolution monitor. Maybe use:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

or use the Toolkit class to get the window bounds.

The `setDividerLocation( double )` method only works on a "realized" frame, which means after you have invoked `pack()` or `setVisible(true)` on the frame.

Or, you need to wrap code in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to make sure the code executes in the proper order. Something like

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        splitPaneLeft.setDividerLocation(165);
        splitPaneRight.setDividerLocation(830);
    }
});
```

If that doesn't work then maybe each statement will need to be done in a separate invokeLater().

Same comment about the divider locations. Don't hard code the values. Maybe you can use the `setDividerLocation(.25f)` method with allocates size by percentage instead of absolute value.

Comment: invokelater on the right splitpane did the trick, Thanks! And I get that setting hard values arent proper, but it's because it's just a testing setup! Any proper windowresizing can always be done later